# Selective column with data from a large pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, column-selection

I have a large dataframe with 1000 columns. I need to pick columns where they do not start with a particular string and assign it to another dataframe. How can I do this?

Something like below:

```
prefixes = ['fit test and human sorry',"perspectum liver scanaccurate","the following tests were not","apo b to  a ratio.this is a useful","psa"]
df_new = [ele for ele in prefixes if(ele.lower() not in df.columns)][0]
```

Comment: Pls explain better. You want to filter out columns which column names start with one of the strings in the list?

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler version:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'steve':[1,2,3],'bob':[1,2,3],'rob':[1,2,3]})
prefixes = ('s', 'r')
df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith(prefixes)]]

   bob
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns you want and filter the DataFrame. Note that the prefixes need to be a tuple.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'abc': [1, 2, 3], 'bcd': [4, 5, 6], 'cde': [7, 8, 9]})

prefixes_to_remove = ('a', 'b')

df_new_columns = [col for col in df.columns if not col.startswith(prefixes_to_remove)]

new_df = df[df_new_columns]
```

This  will yield:

```
   cde
0    7
1    8
2    9
```